# Template Route Already in use

Tags: templates, routing, template-routes

EE 2.9.0

I'm attempting to set up a template route for a new section of the site I'm working on. However when I do I get the error: **Template Route Already in use**

I've set up a route for the blog/single template which works `/blog/{blog-post:alpha_dash}`

However when I try to set one of up for about/single `/about/news/{news-post:alpha_dash}` The CP highlights both the blog and about/single template and says Route Already in use. Also won't let me set segment required on the about route.

When I refresh the page the blog route is there, but the about route is gone. See attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The problem is having no rule and having `alpha_dash` are exactly the same thing, so the error message is correct, those are duplicate routes. If you added the `:pagination` rule to the `{pagination}` variable, then it should work:

```
/about/news/{pagination:pagination}
```

Also, you'll need to have the `{pagination:pagination}` rule first, since `alpha_dash` would catch any pagination.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Sean. Now, we have a problem. I already had this discussion with EllisLab, but I believe you should too. Their answer was to use something like:

```
/about/news/{news-post:alpha_dash}/{pagination}
```

And to set required segments to no. This way, the route will match:

```
/about/news/{news-post:alpha_dash}/{pagination}
/about/news/{news-post:alpha_dash}
/about/news/{pagination}
```

For me, this makes no sense. In my opinion, the previous segment should always be required because we don't use URLs like `/about/news//something`.

I prefer to be able to use something like:

```
/about/news/{news-post:alpha_dash}|{pagination}
```

By the way, `alpha_dash` will match pagination too.

Comment: >  By the way, alpha_dash will match pagination too.

That's the key, when compiled to regex, you have conflicting rules. The `|` option is intriguing, but for now, not requiring segments should work.

> because we don't use URLs like /about/news//something

The chances of a user or even a crawler trying that URL when you aren't linking to it are minuscule—so much that it's probably not worth the time to trap, but if that's a particular concern, you can always use segment conditionals to check for an empty segment and redirect to a 404.

Comment: Oh, SE, why don't you support multi-line comments...